# turn off keyboard back-lit on Gygabyte Sabre 15

Tags: 16.04, drivers, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-backlight

I've recently buy a Gygabyte Sabre 15 computer and intalled on it Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome.

It seem this computer is realy not ready for linux beacaute i've many problems to make ubuntu work correctly with this computer...

Today, I try to resolve my problem with my keyboard bak-lit : The keyboard backlit is always On and I cant turn it off...

After many search, i've found 2 commands : xset led off and xset -led but when I launch this commands, nothing append... No error and keybord backlit is always on...

Someone have an idea on how to solve this problem ?
Thank's in advance !

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have the same problem with my sabre 17

Comment: No, unfortunately, after many hours of search, I did not find any working solutiuon